# Use MEF2 on ASP MVC 4 with .NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mef

I would like to know if there are plans to bring MEF2 and specifically MEF to ASP MVC integration back to .NET 4.0?

I currently have to use .NET 4.0 due to service provider limitation and I am using MEF to ASP MVC integration by using old MEF code from CodePlex. This works but it not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

code from codeplex? but is under composition namespace...

MEF is a part of the Microsoft .NET Framework, with types primarily under the *System.ComponentModel.Composition*.* namespaces.

- MEF has shipped with .NET 4.0 (include asp mvc) and Silverlight 4
- MEF 2 is under development

  - New features are available in pre-release versions of the .NET Framework 4.5
  - Windows 8 Store apps are supported via NuGet

Comment: You right, I mean MEF2. I use the RegistrationBuilder feature